# .htaccess file to redirect all pages except the wp-admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have redirected the all pages of my wp site from .php extension to /
For example, I am redirect pages such as example.com/about-us.php to  example.com/about-us/ but, It is also redirecting my example.com/wp-admin dashboard page which I don't want to redirect.How can I prevent it from redirecting? Here is my .htaccess code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want the 301 redirect (`R=301`)? Surely you want the URL to *look* like it doesn't have .php but under the hood you still want to access the respective php script?

Anyway, how about this - two conditions:

1. must not have `wp-` in the request URI
2. must end in `.php`

Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: yes! i just want to hide the .php extension and my code is working but,when I log into the wordpress admin pannel it is redirecting it to user login page and i am unable to go to the wp dashboard page